# How to close/collapse a nav drawer/tab on mobile with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mobile, tabs

I've tried some simple solutions to get this JS to work with tabs, and everything operates well except that I want it to close the tab drawer on mobile when clicked and can't get it functioning. I feel like there is an easy solution but I can't seem to figure it out. Some help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
/* if in tab mode (laptop) */
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

  $(".tab_content").hide();
  var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
  $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn();        

  $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");

  $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
  $(".tab_drawer_heading[rel^='"+activeTab+"']").addClass("d_active");
});

/* if in drawer mode (mobile) */ 
$(".tab_drawer_heading").click(function() {

  $(".tab_content").hide();
  var d_activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
  $("#"+d_activeTab).fadeIn();

  $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
  $(this).addClass("d_active");

  $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
  $("ul.tabs li[rel^='"+d_activeTab+"']").addClass("active");
});
```

```css
ul.tabs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-size: 0.88em;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

ul.tabs li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0px 21px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  color: grey;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

ul.tabs li:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: #333;
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
  border-left: 1px solid #333;
  border-right: 1px solid #333;
}

ul.tabs li.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
  border-left: 1px solid #333;
  border-right: 1px solid #333;
  display: block;
}

.tab_container {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  border-top: none;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
}

.tab_content {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  display: none;
}

.tab_drawer_heading { display: none; }

@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
  .tabs {
      display: none;
  }

  .tab_drawer_heading {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
      color: #333;
      border-top: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 14px 20px;
      display: block;
      font-size: 0.8em;
      letter-spacing: 4px;
      -webkit-touch-callout: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -khtml-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
  }
  .d_active {
      background-color: darkgrey;
      color: #fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="active" rel="tab1">Tab 1</li>
  <li rel="tab2">Tab 2</li>
</ul>
<div class="tab_container">
  <h3 class="d_active tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab1">Tab 1</h3>
  <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
  <h2>Tab 1 content</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac metus augue.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- #tab1 -->
  <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab2">Tab 2</h3>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
  <h2>Tab 2 content</h2>
    <p>Nunc dui velit, scelerisque eu placerat volutpat, dapibus eu nisi. Vivamus eleifend vestibulum odio non vulputate.</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem in the easiest way without selecting any elements:

```js
var control = false;

$(".tab_drawer_heading").click(function() {  
  if(control != true)
  {
    $("#"+d_activeTab).fadeIn();
    control = true;
  }
  else
  {
    $("#"+d_activeTab).fadeOut();
    control = false;
  }
});
```

```js
var control = false;

$(".tab_drawer_heading").click(function() {
  $(".tab_content").hide();
  var d_activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
  
  if(control != true)
  {
    $("#"+d_activeTab).fadeIn();
    control = true;
  }
  else
  {
    $("#"+d_activeTab).fadeOut();
    control = false;
  }

  $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
  $(this).addClass("d_active");
  $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
  $("ul.tabs li[rel^='"+d_activeTab+"']").addClass("active");
});

$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
  $(".tab_content").hide();
  var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
  $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn();        
  $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");  $(".tab_drawer_heading[rel^='"+activeTab+"']").addClass("d_active");
});
```

```css
ul.tabs {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    width: 100%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-size: 0.88em;
    margin-top: 2em;
}
ul.tabs li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0px 21px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
    color: grey;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

ul.tabs li:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: #333;
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
    border-left: 1px solid #333;
    border-right: 1px solid #333;
}

ul.tabs li.active {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
    border-left: 1px solid #333;
    border-right: 1px solid #333;
    display: block;
}
.tab_container {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    border-top: none;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
}
.tab_content {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    display: none;
}
.tab_drawer_heading { display: none; }
@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
    .tabs {
        display: none;
    }
    .tab_drawer_heading {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
        color: #333;
        border-top: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 14px 20px;
        display: block;
        font-size: 0.8em;
        letter-spacing: 4px;
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }
    .d_active {
        background-color: darkgrey;
        color: #fff;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="active" rel="tab1">Tab 1</li>
  <li rel="tab2">Tab 2</li>
</ul>

<h3 class="d_active tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab1">Tab 1</h3>
<div class="tab_container">
  <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
  <h2>Tab 1 content</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac metus augue.</p>
</div>

<h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab2">Tab 2</h3>
<div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
  <h2>Tab 2 content</h2>
  <p>Nunc dui velit, scelerisque eu placerat volutpat, dapibus eu nisi. Vivamus eleifend vestibulum odio non vulputate.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @problemneedsasolution This way, does the project work the way you want it to? I asked for confirmation if I misunderstood the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem still exists even after adding the jquery reference you suggested. Opening the tabs works perfectly. The problem is that the tabs/drawers don't close (hide the content) when clicked on mobile. I want the active tab to close when clicked again on mobile. Hopefully, I was clear enough with my explanation (English isn't my native language).

Comment: @problemneedsasolution Is this the solution?

Comment: That's actually quite good. However, when I click on the tab on mobile to close it, the tab first flashes to "fadeIn" the content and then Fades out to hide the content. It's a nice solution but It would be amazing to get it functioning flawlessly.

Comment: The problem is not in the solution I developed. The application you have already developed works in this way.

Comment: I have included your implementation in the code snippet. You can look at how it works in your own question.

Comment: Ahh, I see. When I initially tried to implement your solution I missed that I had       $("#"+d_activeTab).fadeIn(); in there two times. This is the solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: With your implementation, I can now open and close a tab on mobile. However, if I open a tab and then don't click to close it but click on the second tab to open it, it closes the first tab but doesn't open the second tab without a second click. Is there an easy fix for that?

Comment: In the solution I developed, you should select the other tab where there is `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`, and where there is `fadeOut`, you should select the other tab and `fadeIn`. This will not be an easy application.